# OOP: what happens when a class is changed after an object is already created from it?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'bla';
}

var theO = new theClass();

function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'lol';
}

//theO.foo = 'bla' or 'lol' when called?
```

Will `theO.foo` be 'bla' or 'lol' when called after the class is redefined?

Comment: "I realize I could just test it myself" - Feel free to answer your question when you find out :)

Comment: Because `function foo() {}` is equivalent with `var foo = function foo() {};` and because of variable hoisting, both should display `lol`.

Comment: It won't be `lol` because changing the "class" somehow changed the object retroactively. It will be `lol` because the "class" *isn't* changed *after* an object is created, due to function hoisting (i.e. functions declared by `function name() { body(); }` are executed first, then everything else.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Those two things are not equivalent; the latter would not be hoisted. `function a() { console.log("a"); } a(); function a() { console.log("b"); }` prints `b`; but `var a = function() { console.log("a"); }; a(); var a = function() { console.log("b"); }` prints `a`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function declarations are  hoisted to the top of their JavaScript scope by the JavaScript interpreter.

Then,

```
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'bla';
}
var theO = new theClass();
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'lol';
}
```

becomes

```
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'bla';
}
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'lol';
}
var theO = new theClass();
```

Therefore, the `theClass` is overridden at the beginning, so `theO.foo` is `'lol'`.

However, it's different with function expressions:

```
var theClass;
theClass = function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'bla';
};
var theO = new theClass();
theClass = function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'lol';
};
```

in this case, `theClass` is overridden after instantiating it, so `theO.foo` is `'bla'`.

Comment: thanks, i'm really impressed with the speed the question is answered. I'm marking this as the accepted answer, but everyone have helped me better understand javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It will be "lol" because the second function override the first one. Javascript parses the functions first. So your code after parsing will be:

```
function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'bla';
}

function theClass() {
  this.foo = 'lol';
}

var theO = new theClass();
```